# VBA function call: Excel Button vs VBS call

Tags: vba, vbscript

I'm struggling with a VBA Sub that is called by a button. This Sub opens an Configuration.xls Excel spreadsheet from a hard coded file path. A MsgBox tell me about the current workspace - the workspace changes from the current file to the just opened one. All is fine here.

I now want to execute this Sub from an outside batch that calls a VBS that calls the VBA Sub. The workspace after opening the Configuration.xls file remains the same and does not change to Configuration.xls. Additionally when calling the Sub by VBS the function gets executed twice - No clue why.

So my question is - why do I have different behaviors between the two calling mechanisms?

I simplified the code below as it shows the same behavior as my more complex real code.

```
Sub ReadConfiguration()

MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
FileExcel = "D:\_Trash\VBA_VBS\Configuration.xls"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileExcel, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
strFileName = FunctionGetFileName(FileExcel)
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name

On Error Resume Next
Set wBook = Workbooks(strFileName)
If Err Then
    Exit Sub
End If
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
'*****************************************************
Function FunctionGetFileName(FullPath As Variant)
Dim StrFind As String
Do Until Left(StrFind, 1) = "\"
    iCount = iCount + 1
    StrFind = Right(FullPath, iCount)
    If iCount = Len(FullPath) Then Exit Do
Loop
FunctionGetFileName = Right(StrFind, Len(StrFind) - 1)
End Function
'*****************************************************
```

The VBS looks like this

```
Dim args, objExcel
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.Run "Module1.ReadConfiguration()"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: I can reproduce your problem no matter it's a sub/a function. Good question, I always followed example online without (). I would like to know what's happening with the ().

Answer (score 0):

I just want to let you know about the solution of this issue allthough I cannot explain completely. The solution is to get rid of the "()" behind the macro call. This has the effect that the VBS script is run twice and the Workbook 'scope' is mixed up.

So easy solution but still the question WHY- What do I tell the function additionally when adding the "()"?

Thanks for your help!

TheMadMatt